# Deleteing or adding items from Redux is slow

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

i try to delete or add my set item from my exercise list, which is stored in my redux store. I got the issue that if i try to delete or add a set, it takes quit a while that the item gets deleted or added.
Therefor when i delete multiple sets on after the other really quick it only deletes on item of my list.

Is their a way to improve my reducer function in my redux store?

Or is their another way to wait for the delete action to finish before the next one starts?

[Video](https://fhstp-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/it201503_fhstp_ac_at/ERIQVGOrsSNNo52yyWb7hysBIDwnX3TVMwoyDUTKID4YPw?e=DD3WCI)

If you need more code please let me know!

**Reducer Function**

```
case DELETE_SET_WORKOUT_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            workout: {
                ...state.workout,
                exerciseList: state.workout.exerciseList.map(exerciseListItem => {
                    if (exerciseListItem.elid !== action.payload.elid) {
                        return exerciseListItem;
                    }
                    return {
                        ...exerciseListItem,
                        sets: exerciseListItem.sets.filter((set) => set.sid !== action.payload.sid)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

**Object structure**

```
workout: {
    exerciseList:[
        item1: {
            sets:[]
        },
        item2: {
            sets:[]
        }
        item3: {
            sets:[
                set1,
                set2,
                set3    <- e.g. Item which should be deleted
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It depends on how big is your state object, also if you are making any api call which is causing the delay?

Comment: By looking at the name `DELETE_SET_WORKOUT_SUCCESS`, I would say it's definitely an asynchronous logic.

Comment: In this action there is no api call involved

Comment: I added the structure of the object in my store @RajdeepDebnath

Comment: Do you have a lot of data in your state? Like lots of workout or exerciselist or item?

Comment: Not really. Every user got 1 workout which can contain multiple exercises with multiple sets. At the moment i got an example workout with 2 exercises and 3 sets each @RajdeepDebnath

Comment: So is there a way to improve my code? @RajdeepDebnath

Comment: It looks your state object is small, so there should not be any reason for the slowness. You can delete the node_modules folder and reinstall by `npm install` and try. Also you can put this code block so that it returns the state in a variable and then log time before and after the operation which will tell you if this code block is the issue. Like `let returnState = {
            ...state,
            workout: {
                ...state.workout,
                ..............................`